# Multiple errors when running example pyqtgraph program (mainly sip type errors)

Tags: python, anaconda, spyder, pyqtgraph

I have been trying to make some graphs in pyqt5 that can update more quickly and efficiently than my currently embedded matplotlib ones.

I keep running into the same problem whenever I run any example code including pyqtgraph, which always throw the following error:
`"TypeError: isdeleted() argument 1 must be sip.simplewrapper, not PlotWidget"`

Environment:

Spyder 3.3.2 Python 3.7.1 64-bit | Qt 5.9.6 | PyQt5 5.9.2 | Windows 10.
After running `pip freeze` I learned my versions are numpy==1.20.1, PyQt5==5.15.2, PyQt5-sip==12.8.1, pyqtgraph==0.11.1

I'm using a very simple test graph from a turial ([Link](https://www.learnpyqt.com/tutorials/plotting-pyqtgraph/)).

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from pyqtgraph import PlotWidget, plot
import pyqtgraph as pg
import sys  # We need sys so that we can pass argv to QApplication
import os

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.graphWidget = pg.PlotWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.graphWidget)

        hour = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
        temperature = [30,32,34,32,33,31,29,32,35,45]

        # plot data: x, y values
        self.graphWidget.plot(hour, temperature)


def main():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    main = MainWindow()
    main.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The code which causes the error most recent in traceback is in "Qt.py", in the following code:

```
# Common to PyQt4 and 5
if QT_LIB in [PYQT4, PYQT5]:
    QtVersion = QtCore.QT_VERSION_STR
    
    try:
        from PyQt5 import sip
    except ImportError:
        import sip
    def isQObjectAlive(obj):
        return not sip.isdeleted(obj)
    
    loadUiType = uic.loadUiType

    QtCore.Signal = QtCore.pyqtSignal
```

The full traceback is much longer, and is as follows:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyqtgraph\graphicsItems\GraphicsObject.py", line 40, in itemChange
    ret = sip.cast(ret, QtGui.QGraphicsItem)

TypeError: cast() argument 1 must be sip.simplewrapper, not PlotItem

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyqtgraph\graphicsItems\ViewBox\ViewBox.py", line 438, in resizeEvent
    self.updateAutoRange()

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyqtgraph\graphicsItems\ViewBox\ViewBox.py", line 890, in updateAutoRange
    childRange = self.childrenBounds(frac=fractionVisible)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyqtgraph\graphicsItems\ViewBox\ViewBox.py", line 1355, in childrenBounds
    px, py = [v.length() if v is not None else 0 for v in self.childGroup.pixelVectors()]

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyqtgraph\graphicsItems\GraphicsItem.py", line 189, in pixelVectors
    dt = self.deviceTransform()

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyqtgraph\graphicsItems\GraphicsItem.py", line 108, in deviceTransform
    view = self.getViewWidget()

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyqtgraph\graphicsItems\GraphicsItem.py", line 65, in getViewWidget
    if v is not None and not isQObjectAlive(v):

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyqtgraph\Qt.py", line 328, in isQObjectAlive
    return not sip.isdeleted(obj)

TypeError: isdeleted() argument 1 must be sip.simplewrapper, not PlotWidget

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyqtgraph\graphicsItems\GraphicsObject.py", line 40, in itemChange
    ret = sip.cast(ret, QtGui.QGraphicsItem)

TypeError: cast() argument 1 must be sip.simplewrapper, not PlotDataItem

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyqtgraph\graphicsItems\GraphicsObject.py", line 40, in itemChange
    ret = sip.cast(ret, QtGui.QGraphicsItem)

TypeError: cast() argument 1 must be sip.simplewrapper, not PlotDataItem

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyqtgraph\graphicsItems\GraphicsObject.py", line 26, in itemChange
    self.parentChanged()

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyqtgraph\graphicsItems\GraphicsItem.py", line 463, in parentChanged
    self._updateView()

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyqtgraph\graphicsItems\GraphicsItem.py", line 480, in _updateView
    view = self.getViewBox()

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyqtgraph\graphicsItems\GraphicsItem.py", line 88, in getViewBox
    vb = self.getViewWidget()

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyqtgraph\graphicsItems\GraphicsItem.py", line 65, in getViewWidget
    if v is not None and not isQObjectAlive(v):

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyqtgraph\Qt.py", line 328, in isQObjectAlive
    return not sip.isdeleted(obj)

TypeError: isdeleted() argument 1 must be sip.simplewrapper, not PlotWidget

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyqtgraph\graphicsItems\GraphicsObject.py", line 40, in itemChange
    ret = sip.cast(ret, QtGui.QGraphicsItem)

TypeError: cast() argument 1 must be sip.simplewrapper, not ChildGroup

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-2-5f5dea77ec5e>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('C:/Users/dowdt/GoogleDrive/Documents/Purdue/GraduateSchool/Homologation/Software/Python Test Code/Python GUI practice/pyqt5LiveGraphExample.py', wdir='C:/Users/dowdt/GoogleDrive/Documents/Purdue/GraduateSchool/Homologation/Software/Python Test Code/Python GUI practice')

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 704, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 108, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "C:/Users/dowdt/GoogleDrive/Documents/Purdue/GraduateSchool/Homologation/Software/Python Test Code/Python GUI practice/pyqt5LiveGraphExample.py", line 30, in <module>
    main()

  File "C:/Users/dowdt/GoogleDrive/Documents/Purdue/GraduateSchool/Homologation/Software/Python Test Code/Python GUI practice/pyqt5LiveGraphExample.py", line 24, in main
    main = MainWindow()

  File "C:/Users/dowdt/GoogleDrive/Documents/Purdue/GraduateSchool/Homologation/Software/Python Test Code/Python GUI practice/pyqt5LiveGraphExample.py", line 19, in __init__
    self.graphWidget.plot(hour, temperature)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyqtgraph\graphicsItems\PlotItem\PlotItem.py", line 653, in plot
    self.addItem(item, params=params)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyqtgraph\graphicsItems\PlotItem\PlotItem.py", line 530, in addItem
    self.vb.addItem(item, *args, **vbargs)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyqtgraph\graphicsItems\ViewBox\ViewBox.py", line 409, in addItem
    self.updateAutoRange()

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyqtgraph\graphicsItems\ViewBox\ViewBox.py", line 890, in updateAutoRange
    childRange = self.childrenBounds(frac=fractionVisible)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyqtgraph\graphicsItems\ViewBox\ViewBox.py", line 1355, in childrenBounds
    px, py = [v.length() if v is not None else 0 for v in self.childGroup.pixelVectors()]

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyqtgraph\graphicsItems\GraphicsItem.py", line 189, in pixelVectors
    dt = self.deviceTransform()

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyqtgraph\graphicsItems\GraphicsItem.py", line 108, in deviceTransform
    view = self.getViewWidget()

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyqtgraph\graphicsItems\GraphicsItem.py", line 65, in getViewWidget
    if v is not None and not isQObjectAlive(v):

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyqtgraph\Qt.py", line 328, in isQObjectAlive
    return not sip.isdeleted(obj)
TypeError: isdeleted() argument 1 must be sip.simplewrapper, not PlotWidget
```

Comment: Why do you have 2 pyqt? Try changing `from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
` for `from pyqtgraph.Qt import QtGui` and `QtWidgets` for `QtGui`

Comment: I didn't reproduce your error after running the code you provided, it works fine.

Comment: @eyllanesc I don't quite follow. Are you suggesting replacing `from PyQt5 import QtWidgets` with `from pyqtgraph.Qt import QtWidgets`? If so, I seem to get the same error.
@AlejandroCondori Thank you for checking. I will try to run on a separate machine and see if i can reproduce the error or not.

Comment: @Toozinger I think I was clear, change `from PyQt5 import QtWidgets` to `from PyQt5 import QtGui`. I don't reproduce the problem either, I think the cause of the error is anaconda.

Comment: Why do you have PyQt5 5.9.2 and PyQt5==5.15.2?

Comment: @eyllanesc what type of install would you suggest instead of anaconda?
PyQt5 5.9.2 is from the Spyder Help/About tab. PyQt5 5.15.2 is from running the `pip freeze` command in cmd. If I run `from PyQt5.QtCore import QT_VERSION_STR` in the IPython console within Spyder, I get 5.9.6. I'm not sure how or why these are all different.

Comment: So you have 2 python: one installed by anaconda and another who knows. Don't use anaconda, just install python directly since anaconda has many bugs with respect to Qt (if you check the posts you will see it)

Comment: @eyllanesc: Ah, thanks for the tip. I likely accidentally installed it multiple times in my ignorance during trying to set things up. I have run this example script on two separate machines now without issue, so I'll be doing some uninstalling and cleaning of my main machine to hopefully remedy this issue. Thanks for the help debugging.